# $a + b + c, \ ab + bc + ca, \ abc$ Prove a, b and c are real.

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

I have found this problem in a book. If a, b and c are complex numbers, such that $|a| \neq |b| \neq |c| \neq |a|$ and $a + b + c, \ ab + bc + ca, \ abc$ are all real numbers, we must prove $a, \ b, \ c$ are also real numbers. We can get $(a + b + c) ^ 2 \in \ \mathbb {R}$, so $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, using $a ^ 3 + b ^ 3 + c ^ 3 - 3abc = (a + b + c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab -bc-ac) =  3(a + b)(b + c)(a+c)$ I can get $a ^ 3 + b ^ 3 + c ^ 3 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(a+b)(b+c)(a+c) \in \mathbb{R}$. But I cannot fit these to prove that a, b or is real.

Comment: Hint: form a polynomial with roots $a$, $b$, and $c$. What do you know about polynomials with real coefficients?

Comment: Well, I do not think I know very much. :))))) Is there any theorem or lemma I should know about?

Answer (score 3):

By [Vièta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), $a,b,c$ are the roots of
$$x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc$$
All the coefficients of this polynomial are real. If the polynomial has complex roots, there must be one such pair of them *related by conjugation*, but conjugate roots have the same magnitude, which is disallowed by the question. Thus the polynomial has only real roots, i.e. $a,b,c$ are real.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very elegant solution. Is there any other way to solve it as I feel as if I cheated using things I did not learn yet.

Comment: @andueu No other way to solve it.

Comment: Oh, well, that you very much! Is this type of proof used often with complex numbers? I feel like I do not know many strategies for dealing with them.

Comment: @andueu When you see symmetric polynomials like $ab+bc+ca$, Viète's relations may be a good idea.